# Using react hook form v7.31.2, trying to validate an email field giving an error

Tags: react-hook-form

I a using react hook form v7.31.2, trying to validate an email field, but its giving an error, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email'). I would like to pass the email validated message in the `emailValidationText` class. Could someone please advise what is problem here ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

    const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');

        const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log("RESULT", data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
      };
      console.log(errors);

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            {...register("email", { 
                                required: "Email is required",
                                pattern: {
                                    value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                                    message: "Please enter a valid email !"
                                }
                            })}
                        />
                         <span className="emailValidationText">
                             {errors.email && errors.email.message}
                         </span>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            {...register("password", { required: true})}
                        />
                         <label>
                            <span className="loginValidationText">{helperText}</span>
                         </label>
                        <section className="col-low">
                        <input type="submit" />
                        </section>  
                    </form>
```

Comment: You probably solved it already, but if not: since v7 the `errors` object is nested inside the `formState` property, so your destructering of `errors` is returning `undefined`. [Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate)